# ipsec open source for linux

Tags: linux, network-programming, ipsec

What are the open source available for `ipsec` in **linux** today.

I came across 1 (strongswan), but I am very new to this. Please suggest me which is the best available one and scalable.

Comment: you can try openswan as well.

Comment: You can use that one (strongswan) or ipsec-tools packet. They are easy to configure and understand.

Answer (score 1):

if you look into kernel, you may find it.

For example, there is a ipsec.h under 
/include/uapi/linux/

I am not an expert of kernel. Just a clue

Answer (score 0):

I think the document of strongswan is a good start point to understand IPSec. but the source code of strongswan is not friendly enough for learning IPsec implementation.

I would recommend you start from the source code of ip, part of iproute2 utility of GNU tools.